# Where should my security logic go?

Tags: security, oop, single-responsibility-principle, repository-design

Let's say I have an ASP.NET MVC webapp that calls a repository layer, which is built on top of nHibernate. The controller passes the repository an `ISecurityToken` that encapsulates the current user's identity and permissions, and the repository uses it when querying to only return rows the user should be able to see.

I want an entity (a Ticket) to only be closable by a certain group of users, as well as the user a ticket is assigned to. In other words, the hypothetical `CanCloseTicket()` method needs two inputs:

1. The ticket itself (or its current owner ID)
2. The current user's `ISecurityToken`

Where should this hypothetical method live? I can see several possibilities but each has their drawbacks.

- In the controller: The controller has access to everything necessary, but this make leave it possible for the security to be bypassed. ("Oops, I forgot to call CanCloseTicket() in this action before setting `ticket.IsOpen` to false!" This smells bad.
- In the repository: The repository also has access to both pieces, but I'd also have to make `Ticket.IsClosed`'s setter private to stop the same thing above from happening. The repository lives in a totally different assembly than the model so using an internal setters won't work. I could instead leave the setter public and compare the property's current value to its original one, returning an error if an unprivileged user closes it, but this also smells a bit off to me. ("Oops, I forgot to check the return value of `repo.CloseTicket()` in this action method!")
- In the ticket: Adding `Ticket.Close(ISecurityToken token)` and making the entity responsible for its own security logic feels like a violation of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I think the repository is the best option here, but it *feels* more like the least-worst option. Is there anything else?

Comment: What other responsibilities does the `Ticket` class have?

Comment: Aside from its properties (owner, change history, etc), not many. Most of the behavior and business logic (except for the security, as I described in the first paragraph of my question) is in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final option sounds exactly right to me: when someone wants to close a ticket, they have to provide *evidence* in the form of a security token. (Having said that, it's hard enough to judge SRP violations when you have access to a class' source code that I can't say I'm totally confident.)